# Android hashMapValues how to get value and format it

Tags: java, android, string, android-fragments, hashmap

How can I print the value of my HashMap  like this:

String hashMapValues = PHOTO_IDS.get(all values);

hashMapValues output as :
id1, id2, id3, id4, id5

```
HashMap<String,String> PHOTO_IDS;

onCreate....
PHOTO_IDS = new HashMap<String, String>();

if(vc.readLAST_TAKEN_PIC().equals("imageCam1")) { PHOTO_IDS.put("imageCam1", id); }
                   else if(vc.readLAST_TAKEN_PIC().equals("imageCam2")) { PHOTO_IDS.put("imageCam2", id); }
                   else if(vc.readLAST_TAKEN_PIC().equals("imageCam3")) { PHOTO_IDS.put("imageCam3", id); }
                   else if(vc.readLAST_TAKEN_PIC().equals("imageCam4")) { PHOTO_IDS.put("imageCam4", id); }
                   else if(vc.readLAST_TAKEN_PIC().equals("imageCam5")) { PHOTO_IDS.put("imageCam5", id); }
```

many many thanks for help.

UPDATED_____________________________________________

Thank you all for your reply. here is the working code:

```
String hashmapValues = PHOTO_IDS.values().toString();
TMP_PHOTO_ID = hashmapValues.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
```

Comment: You can do it by Sting concatenation.

Comment: @qɘɘbɒɿq could you give me sample pls. thanks

Comment: Did you use `PHOTO_IDS .values()`?

Comment: @MrT check my answer, Pankaj kumar answer is better then mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `entrySet()` to print all values like this:

UPDATE : Using `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for(Entry<String,String> e : PHOTO_IDS.entrySet()){
   s.append(e.getValue() + ", ");
}
String result = s.toString();
```

Refer [HashMap#entrySet() java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet()) for more information.

There is one more way to get the comma-seperated values directly as below :

```
String result = PHOTO_IDS.values().toString();
```

But this will return output as `[id1, id2, id3, id4, id5]`, so you just need to get rid of those brackets`[]` which you can do easily by using `substring`

Comment: thanks for your replay. I need to pass all the values with Comma between each value to a String. Do you know how is this possible ? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Map.getValues()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) for this purpose.

like

```
System.out.println(PHOTO_IDS .values());
```

Output will be like

```
[id1, id2, id3, id4, id5]
```

Here you need to relace `[` and `]` characters from string.

Comment: Wont necessarily print in that order unless using a LinkedHashMap

Comment: @GleasonK So where is order in scene here??

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the brackets around your value list, you can do the following. But for all solutions if you are concerned about order, you may want to consider using a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String val : map.values()){
    sb.append(val+",");
}
String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result.substring(0, result.length() - 1)); //This will remove the last comma.
```